# Get overlapping pairs from character vector

Tags: r

So I have the following character vector

```
xx = c("AAA", "ABC", "CBS")
xx
length(nchar(xx))
```

I'm trying to split this out so that I have each of the strings in the vector as pairs of two. In the above example, it'd look like a data frame where:

```
AAA   ABC
ABC   CBS
```

I've been trying to avoid a loop as my data will be large.

```
split(xx, 2)
split(xx, cut(seq_along(xx), 2, labels = FALSE)) 
split(xx, cut(seq_along(xx), 2, labels = FALSE))[[1]] 
split(xx, cut(seq_along(xx[-1]), 2, labels = FALSE))[[1]]
```

Any suggestions on a solution that avoids a for loop.

With five entries:

```
xx = c("AAA", "ABC", "CBS", "BBB", "GGG")
xx

AAA   ABC
ABC   CBS
CBS   BBB
BBB   GGG
```

Comment: It should be xx[1] and xx[2]. Then xx[2] and xx[3]. It's the the sequence of events, so xx[1] and xx[3] isn't needed in this case.

Comment: So, if we extend to `xx` to have 5 entries how should it be?

Comment: `embed(xx, 2)[, 2:1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
xx = c("AAA", "ABC", "CBS", "BBB", "GGG")

library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(col1 = xx) %>% 
    mutate(col2 = lead(col1)) %>% 
    tidyr::drop_na()
```

Output

```
#   col1 col2
# 1  AAA  ABC
# 2  ABC  CBS
# 3  CBS  BBB
# 4  BBB  GGG
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(as.data.table(xx)[, xx1 := shift(xx, type = "lead")])
#    xx xx1
#1: AAA ABC
#2: ABC CBS
#3: CBS BBB
#4: BBB GGG
```